# Pass windows authentication username to asp variable

Tags: asp-classic

I have a site that processes orders taken by phone into a SQL database. Access to the portal uses Windows Authentication and I would like to pass the username of the order processor along with the order so that I can record who has taken the order.

How can I pass the user name to a form element?

The pages are written in classic asp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once authenticated with Windows Authentication, you can get the username
with `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").`